# Search column for string, if found/or not add another string to a separate column

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Hi I am trying to search a very large .txt file for specific strings in one column of the file found in a separate .txt file.

Depending on whether the string is found/or not in the specified column, I would then like to add another string to a separate column.

For example:

Input file:

```
ID  data    name    Yes_No
1   225     name1   
2   245     name2   
3   355     name3
4   466     name4
5   230     name5
```

File2:

```
ID
1
3
5
```

Desired output:

```
ID  data    name    Yes_No
1   225     name1   1
2   245     name2   0
3   355     name3   1
4   466     name4   0
5   230     name5   1
```

I am hoping this will be straight forward, but I have become stuck! I would greatly appreciate some help.

Thanks

Comment: Is the white space between columns tab chars or blanks or some combination of both or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=1;next}FNR>1{$4=0+a[$1]}7' file2 file1
```

If you want to get a better format, you can pipe the result to `|column -t`

Comment: Thanks for this Kent! Would you mind breaking down how the command works? Thanks

Comment: @hdjc90 tell which part you have problem to understand

Comment: Is the $4 the column? Also what is the number 7 for?

Comment: the 4th column. 7 does default action. read some tutorial like this:https://www.baeldung.com/linux/awk-multiple-input-files#2-print-lines-by-defined-line-numbers

Comment: When I use this on my large file the columns are a bit more complex and it seems to distort the columns if something is missing from the column. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @hdjc90 Setting field separator might help `BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}`

Comment: @hdjc90 if a solution works for the example you provided but not for your real data then you provided a bad example so update your question to provide different sample input/output that, **while still minimal**, is more truly representative of your real data and in particular fails given the current solution you're testing with. There isn't much we can to do help you debug the problem given just `the columns are a bit more complex and it seems to distort the columns`.

Comment: Ed was likely right that this is a tab delimited file. The 'distortions' are likely from not setting the OFS to \t.